# allow anyone to save data to apache server on amazon-ec2 linux instance from html file

Tags: html, apache, amazon-ec2, mechanicalturk

First time poster here, recently self-taught Javascript/html coder. I am running an apache server on an Amazon Linux ec2 instance, and I am able to add/create files fine from the terminal when I log into my ec2-instance. However, I am a psychology researcher, and want to use this platform to run experiments and save data. I have successfully created the experiment on the server using javascript/html/css, but I want the resulting data to be saved to the server when someone completes the experiment.

The link to the experiment is http://13.59.21.210/ApplesAndOranges/colorObjects/ApplesAndOranges_HTML.html.

I attempted to write a function that saves my data to the server (sendToServer() called by saveAllData()), which uses jquery's post method but when I check the save location, no file has been created. I intend to link to this from Amazon Mechanical Turk (mTurk).

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated, and I'm more than happy to provide any other information that might be useful!

Comment: Even with Apache you need a server side environment to receive the data and do something with it.  In effect you've created a "read only" site at this point. There are a huge number of possible ways of implementing the "write" part.  Can you provide a bit more details as to your development environment?  How do you want to read the data back?  Are there security requirements for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is so much useless information; and so much missing information. do have a website to begin with? where is it stored (default place is `/var/www/html`). Are you creating the experiment on the same server where your web server is running? Can you just copy `cp` files to the destination? If not - why not? what are these functions that you are referring to? where are they running? Maybe, respectfully, you can get a Comp Sci friend set you up with the basics; and you can go from there